# PrimeFaces GMap Inside div Element Does Not Show Up

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, primefaces-gmap

I have a GMap inside a `div` with `display:none;`.

Inside the `div` is a PrimeFaces map component.

After clicking on a button, the content of the `div` element should appear, but only a blank page is showing.

```
<div class="form-group" id="mapContainer" style="display:none;">
    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="51.30993291552862,9.448113441467285" zoom="15" type="terrain" style="width:100%;height:700px;" widgetVar="gmap" navigationControl="false" />
</div>
```

But outside the `div` element, the map is built and showing correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So should I mark this as a duplicate question? There **is** an identical one... which you were requested to refer to but you did not... why?

Comment: You can mark it as duplicate, but it doenst solve my problem or it doenst give an answer to my question. :(

Comment: It **does** answer the question, but of if does not work for you, refer to this existing question and state it does not solve it for you, but provide a reak good code example using the non-working answer and thoroughly debug what it **does** do in this case

Comment: Where is this existing question?

Comment: The one you 'wrongly' answered yesterday

Comment: You told me yesterday that, if a question do not provide a solution to my problem.i have to write another one. that's what i did. and now you refer me back to that question.

Comment: REFER to the other question in this question. Mention what is suggested in the other question as an answer and debug on your side what actually happens when you try to apply the solution from the other question.

Comment: Do you initialize a map inside the hidden element? I believe it won't work because the map container has 0 size when it's hidden. You should trigger resize once the div is visible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of comments, google map object is not initialized if `mapContainer` div is hidden (`display: none`) during page load...

so you will need to "manually" initialize [google map object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1) after you make `mapContainer` div visible.

**Here is fully working code** (based on your posted code) that will do what you need:

Add this JavaScript to your page

```
    <script>
        function resizeElement(elementId,width,height){
            console.log("Resizing element " + elementId + " W/H="+ width + "/" + height);

            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);

            element.style.width=width+"px";
            element.style.height=height+"px"
        }

        function resizePfGmapInsideWrapperElement(wrapperElementId){
            var wrapperElement=document.getElementById(wrapperElementId);
            var width=wrapperElement.clientWidth-40;
            var height=wrapperElement.clientHeight-60;

            resizeElement("gmap",width,height);
        }

        function resizePfGmapInsideDiv(){
            var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();
            console.log(gmap);

            resizePfGmapInsideWrapperElement("mapContainer");
        }

        function toggleDivVisibility() {
            var div = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
            if(div.style.display === "block"){
                div.style.display = "none";
            }else{
                div.style.display = "block";
                div.style.width="600px";
                div.style.height="400px";
                initializeGmap();
                resizePfGmapInsideDiv();
            }
        }

        function initializeGmap() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.30993291552862, 9.448113441467285),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }
            new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),myOptions);
         }

    </script>
```

and, just  for testing purposes, add a button that will toggle `mapContainer` div visibility

```
<p:commandButton value="Show/hide map" onclick="toggleDivVisibility();"/>
```

The crucial JS method is self-explanatory `initializeGmap()` executed in the moment when you make div visible: it will create *"a new map inside of the given HTML container, which is typically a DIV element."* as stated in documentation referenced above.